# Combining Select values from MYSQL then refining that fall within a range

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress database with meta_key and meta_value columns in a wp_postmeta table. I am currently trying to select all rows which have a meta_key of _sale_price with a meta_value of > 0:

```
SELECT * FROM `ra_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_sale_price' AND `meta_value` > 0
```

This works fine. However I would like to further refine these results. There are two other `meta_key`s I need to work with, `_sale_price_dates_from` and `_sale_price_dates_to`. I would like to only include rows where todays strototime date, e.g. `1406649975` falls within `_sale_price_dates_from` and `_sale_price_dates_to`. This is because some products have a sale_price of > 0, but are scheduled to go on sale at a later date, I don't want these returned in the result. E.g.

```
_sale_price_dates_from >= 1406649975 AND _sale_price_dates_to <= 1406649975
```

But I don't know SQL well enough to do this.

Is it something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `ra_postmeta` 
WHERE (`meta_key` = '_sale_price' AND `meta_value` > 0) 
AND (`meta_key` = '_sale_price_dates_to' AND ( `meta_value` >= 1406649975 OR `meta_value`=null)) 
AND (`meta_key` = '_sale_price_dates_from' AND ( `meta_value` <= 1406649975 OR `meta_value`=null))
```

(but this returns zero rows)

Thanks

Comment: Are you after the posts that match those criteria or are you just interested in the meta data, or both?

Comment: That looks quite good. Personally, I prefer to make a pseudo-normalized pivot, and then filter in that - but my solution is not necessarily faster.

Comment: I guess I'd like the post_ids that meet that criteria yes. But its not so important - I'm trying to add a clause to an existing query in wordpress - I just don't know how to write the SQL

Comment: I should have said, that query returns no results

Comment: @Strawberry I've no idea what that means, but if its something I can put into an SQL query I'd love to try anything that might work at this point!

Comment: @patrickzdb If you're interested, post up a sqlfiddle, the desired result set, and I'll show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical difficulty that one encounters with the (otherwise flexible) [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

You need to self-join the table once for every type of metadata:

```
SELECT sale_price.post_id

-- first, let's check for the sale price
FROM ra_postmeta AS sale_price

-- then we need to check the "dates to"
-- the LEFT JOIN, instead of (INNER) JOIN, makes the query return all rows from sale_price
-- even if there is no match on "dates_to" (which equates to your "OR meta_value=NULL") clause
LEFT JOIN ra_postmeta AS dates_to
    ON dates_to.meta_id = sale_price.meta_id        -- this is the real JOIN condition
    AND dates_to.meta_key = '_sale_price_dates_to'  -- this selects only meta-data related to "dates to"
    AND dates_to.meta_value >= 1406649975           -- condition on this meta-data

-- then we need to check the "dates from", we take the exact same approach as with "dates to"
LEFT JOIN ra_postmeta AS dates_from
    ON dates_from.meta_id = sale_price.meta_id
    AND dates_from.meta_key = '_sale_price_dates_from'
    AND dates_from.meta_value <= 1406649975

-- finally, the conditions on the first table (in the FROM clause)
WHERE
    sale_price.meta_key = '_sale_price'
    AND sale_price.meta_value > 0
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer and commenting. You had two small typos, next to AND `dates_from.meta_value` and `AND dates_to.meta_key` (back ticks)

Comment: @patrickzdb Thanks, feel free to edit such obvious typos in the future (and earn a full +2 rep for it ;)

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to have to ask another question about how to merge these query commands with the existing WordPress query. This works but I'm not sure how to make it work with the existing query

Answer (score 0):

You need to self-join the meta data by post_id and use `IS NULL` not `= NULL`:

```
SELECT pm1.post_id
FROM ra_postmeta pm1
LEFT JOIN ra_postmeta pm2
  ON pm2.post_id = pm1.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = '_sale_price_dates_to'
LEFT JOIN ra_postmeta pm3
  ON pm3.post_id = pm1.post_id AND pm3.meta_key = '_sale_price_dates_from'
WHERE pm1.meta_key = '_sale_price'
  AND pm1.meta_value > 0
  AND pm2.meta_value >= 1406649975 OR pm2.meta_value IS NULL
  AND pm3.meta_value <= 1406649975 OR pm3.meta_value IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried that in phpmyadmin and I got  #1054 - Unknown column 'p2.meta_key' in 'on clause'.

Comment: Thanks, I've waited about 2 minutes now but its still trying to load. Think it may have timed out..

Comment: Ah sorry, it got there in the end... Thanks. Not sure about using this on a production site if it takes so long though. But thanks for your help